# OnLongClickListiner is not working

Tags: java, android, onlongclicklistener

The code throws compile time error:

```
Class 'Anonymous class derived from OnLongClickLister' is not abstract and does not override abstract method onLongClick(View) in OnLongClickListener
```

Code:

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button amitsbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amitsbutton);

            amitsbutton.setOnClickListener(
                    new Button.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            TextView amitstext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amitstext);
                            amitstext.setText("Small click is working");
                        }
                    }
            );

            amitsbutton.setOnLongClickListener(
                    new Button.OnLongClickListener() {
                        public boolean OnLongClick(View v) {
                            TextView amitstext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amitstext);
                            amitstext.setText("long click is also working ");
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
            );
```

Comment: `@Override` the  `onLongClick`method

Comment: and return false from setOnClickListener onClick

Comment: why should he return false? It should return true since the click was consumed

Comment: thanx..it worked..what happens if we return false

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3894844/3926727

Comment: @rasel he is indeed consuming the event, so it's appropriate to return true. Anyway in this case returning false wouldn't change anything, but I consider it a bad practise

Answer (score 0):

You're not overriding the right method. It's `onLongClick`, not `OnLongClick`. See below:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button amitsbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amitsbutton);

        amitsbutton.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        TextView amitstext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amitstext);
                        amitstext.setText("Small click is working");
                    }
                }
        );

        amitsbutton.setOnLongClickListener(
                new Button.OnLongClickListener() {
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        TextView amitstext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amitstext);
                        amitstext.setText("long click is also working ");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        );
```